# Need to get a file from an old windows laptop

Tags: windows

I have two laptops: one lenovo ideapad 110s currently running with Linux and a hp pavilion dm4 beats edition with Windows 8 which has been being very difficult since I spilt a drink on the keypad.

I just need to extract a file from the damaged laptop, 2 megabytes at that. I've tried plugging in an external keyboard and it doesn't work. It used to work by putting in sleep mode and restarting and the external keyboard would work, but recently this doesn't work nor will it let me activate the on-screen keyboard.

How can I use Ubuntu to retrieve the file?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu? This is a hardware issue.

Comment: Is there any way I can skip the login process? My mouse works perfectly I just need to copy a file to google drive. I just can't get past the frickin login screen because my keyboard or any keyboard for that matter won't friggin work....

Comment: @wjandrea. It doesn't I suppose. Other than the fact i'm using ubuntu to ask the question. Maybe i can boot from ubuntu? I don't know. I'm reaching for straws here man.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to put the hard drive in another PC to recover the file.

Comment: BTW this should be a lesson to make backups of your important files.

Comment: @wjandrea thanks for the life lesson mom. Didn't forget to backup an entire hard drive. Just a 2 megabyte file. Leave it to jesus. And it's a laptop  not a desktop. Not entirely sure how to remove a laptop hard drive and connect it to... anything

Comment: See [How to disassemble HP Pavilion dm4](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/disassemble-hp-pavilion-dm4-laptop/) up to step 4. Or take it to a shop.

Comment: I would like to avoid dissembling it if possible. It seems like a last resort.

Comment: I also do not know how to retrieve a file from a laptop hard drive even if I did remove it. Sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ubuntu live usb to start the machine without installing anything and then use your working mouse to move the file to an external USB disk or to Google drive by finding the link in the history tab of your browser.